# Optimal build for Saw Cleaver, Ludwig's Holy Blade, and Rifle Spear…

Tags: bloodborne

What would an optimal progression look like to use a combination of the Saw Cleaver, Ludwig's Holy Blade, and the Rifle Spear be?

My character's current states are:

- *Level* 47.
- *Vitality* 21.
- *Endurance* 20.
- *Strength* 20.
- *Skill* 21.
- *Bloodtinge* 9.
- *Arcane* 6.

I am quite fond of the [Saw Cleaver](http://www.bloodborne-wiki.com/2015/03/saw-cleaver.html), [Ludwig's Holy Blade](http://www.bloodborne-wiki.com/2015/03/ludwigs-holy-blade.html), and the [Rifle Spear](http://www.bloodborne-wiki.com/2015/03/rifle-spear.html). I do have a [Hunter Axe](http://www.bloodborne-wiki.com/2015/03/hunters-axe.html) but I am finding it awkward to use due to the high endurance cost -- although a charged R2 can one-shot many enemies. All my weapons are currently on +4. I just opened the Forbidden Woods and the first Phumeru dungeon. I know of the 25 soft limit so points invested in early state might be better than in late ones.

Comment: Your build is up to you, really. But on top of that, unless I'm mistaken, those three weapons you've listed have vastly different scaling, so there isn't a single build that will be optimal for all three of them. You'd be much better off picking one of them and sticking to it the entire game. That's the most efficient/effective way to get through the Souls games. Pick a weapon and intimately familiarize yourself with it/upgrade it to the maximum level. The game seems like it is trying to nudge you in that direction anyways, since there's only one item to raise a weapon to max in the whole game

Comment: Have a read into [Soft Caps](http://bloodborne.wiki.fextralife.com/Stats) for your stats. This can help you identify how to build your character, to optimise them based on the weapon you choose. Other than that, As @Vemonus stated already, it's really just up to you.